# Android/Kotlin - How to loop all the ToggleButtons to make a condition of if/else

Tags: android, for-loop, if-statement, button, kotlin

I have the following group of `toggleButtons` (the green one is checked, and the other ones are unchecked) in an `adapter`:

[image]

I'm trying to find a solution **to not do this** in all the toggleButtons:

```
           holder.eleven.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if(isChecked == true){
                    holder.eleven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                } else {
                    holder.eleven.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                }
            }
```

**I want to have a if/else statement which will do the previous work (set text color) for all the** `toggleButtons`.

I've tried to specify an array to run in an loop but **did not work**:

```
           val array = arrayOf(R.id.one,
                    R.id.two,
                    R.id.three,
                    R.id.four,
                    R.id.five,
                    R.id.six,
                    R.id.seven,
                    R.id.eight,
                    R.id.nine,
                    R.id.ten,
                    R.id.eleven)
            for (i in array.indices) {
                array[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                    if (isChecked) {
                        array[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                    } else {
                        array[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                    }
                }
             }
```

Do you know how I can make this better? Thanks.

Comment: I really don't get this question. Can you specify what exactly you want?

Comment: @DevMike I want to have a if/else statement which will do the work for all the toogleButtons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array should be:

```
val array = arrayOf(
    holder.one, holder.two, holder.three, holder.four, holder.five, holder.six, 
    holder.seven,  holder.eight, holder.nine, holder.ten, holder.eleven)
```

and then:

```
for (i in array.indices) {
    array[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        array[i].setTextColor(if (isChecked) Color.WHITE else Color.BLACK)
    }
}
```

or:

```
array.forEach { 
   it.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
       v.setTextColor(if (isChecked) Color.WHITE else Color.BLACK)
   } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the "_dor", it doesn't exist, it was a mistake. Thank you for the response.

Comment: So you need only 1 array?

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong. You have an array of Int, and then you try to set listeners on those Ints. That's not going to work.

Try this instead:

```
//I recommend putting this array inside a companion object or as a global variable
//There's no need to reinitialize it every time the containing method is called
val buttons = arrayOf(
    R.id.one,
    R.id.two,
    R.id.three,
    R.id.four,
    R.id.five,
    R.id.six,
    R.id.seven,
    R.id.eight,
    R.id.nine,
    R.id.ten,
    R.id.eleven
)

//No need to manually reference an index and then retrieve it.
//Kotlin does it for you
buttons.forEach { //"it" is a reference to the current array element
    val button = holder.findViewById<ToggleButton>(it)

    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        //if-else statements are expressions in Kotlin, and can be used like Java ternaries
        //which simplifies your expression
        button.setTextColor(if (isChecked) Color.WHITE else Color.BLACK)
    }
}
```

<sub>(By the way, unless you're using something else, it's ToggleButton, not ToogleButton.)</sub>

Comment: Sorry about the "_dor", it doesn't exist, it was a mistake. Thank you for the response.

Comment: So there's only the `one`, `two`, etc, as ToggleButtons? That makes this easier.